# How to focus on frame in wxpython?

Tags: wxpython

I have set focused on the button and used the event **wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS** to set `focus . I am using the Raised method to brings back a frame to the foreground. The things happening here is, if I continuously press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> the frame goings to fickle. It takes some time to resolve.

***Now my question is, how to set focus on a frame?***

If I press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> or any other combinations frame should be focus. please advice

***Here is my code:***

```
import wx
import sys

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Focus Tutorial 1a")

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.SetWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        self.Show()
        self.ShowFullScreen(True) 
        self.Maximize(True)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ACTIVATE, self.onClose1)
        btn = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Test")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClose)
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_SET_FOCUS, self.onFocus)
        #btn.Bind(wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS, self.onKillFocus)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
       sizer.Add(txt, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def onClose(self, event):
        sys.exit(0)

    def onClose1(self, event):
        self.Raise()
        print "widget lost focus!"

    def onFocus(self, event):
        self.Raise()
        self.SetWindowStyle(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        print "widget received focus!"

    def onKillFocus(self, event):
        self.Raise()
        print "widget lost focus!"


# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: It is explained well, here https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/27/wxpython-learning-to-focus/ "wx.Panel only accepts focus when it does not have a child widget that can accept focus. "

Comment: This should work: `self.SetFocus()`.